# caret: different RMSE on the same data

Tags: r, r-caret

I think, that my problem is quite weird. When I use RMSE metric for the best model selection by `train` function, I obtain different RMSE value from computed by my own function on the same data. Where ist the problem? Does my function work wrong?

```
library(caret)
library(car)
library(nnet)


data(oil)
ztest=fattyAcids[c(81:96),]

fit<-list(r1=c(1:80)) 
pred<-list(r1=c(81:96)) 
ctrl <- trainControl(method = "LGOCV",index=fit,indexOut=pred)



model <- train(Palmitic~Stearic+Oleic+Linoleic+Linolenic+Eicosanoic, 
               fattyAcids, 
               method='nnet', 
               linout=TRUE, 
               trace=F,
               maxit=10000,
               skip=F,
               metric="RMSE",

               tuneGrid=expand.grid(.size=c(10,11,12,9),.decay=c(0.005,0.001,0.01)),
               trControl = ctrl,
               preProcess = c("range"))
model
forecast <- predict(model, ztest)

Blad<-function(zmienna,prognoza){

  RMSE<-((sum((zmienna-prognoza)^2))/length(zmienna))^(1/2)

  estymatory <- c(RMSE)
  names(estymatory) <-c('RMSE') 
  estymatory
}
Blad(ztest$Palmitic,forecast)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The resampled estimates shown in the output of `train` are calculated using rows `81:96`. Once `train` figures out the right tuning parameter settings, it refits using all the data (`1:96`). The model from that data is used to make the new predictions.

For this reason, the model performance

```
> getTrainPerf(model)
  TrainRMSE TrainRsquared method
1 0.9230175     0.8364212   nnet
```

is worse than the other predictions:

```
> Blad(ztest$Palmitic,forecast)
     RMSE 
0.3355387
```

The predictions in `forecast` are created from a model that included those same data points, which is why it looks better.

Max

Comment: plus, `caret` returns the average RMSE for each CV (or data split), so there's model averaging which makes the accuracy values lower than the best model values. Am I right? One can see the individual values using `model$resample`.